# how to check a string against a firebase value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have search feature with in my app and it works fine for things that are in the database. But when the item is not in my database I get a fatal error.

The search function has an edittext an a button when the button is fired it checks the database for a reference to the edittext.

This is my code.

```
    public void searchfunction() {
    mArraylist.clear();
    final ChildEventListener msearchevent = new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            String msearchname = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);

            final String url = dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);

            if (msearchname.toLowerCase().contains(searchapps.toLowerCase())) {
                marrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mArraylist);
                mlv.setAdapter(marrayAdapter2);

                mArraylist.add(msearchname);
                mArraylist2.add(url);
                marrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mlv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        DownloadFileFromURL dl = new DownloadFileFromURL(mContext, apkNames, mCurrentPhotoPath);
                        dl.execute(mArraylist2.get(position));
                    }
                });

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No results found!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }


        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            marrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            marrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            marrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            marrayAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    mListRef.child("Filmapps").addChildEventListener(msearchevent);
```

My button click is handled within a GetView function
this is the code for my button click

```
 mgoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        searchapps = msearch.getText().toString().trim();
        searchfunction();
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
});

06-27 17:51:16.708 2938-2938/com.example.harrops.h20droidapp2 E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.harrops.h20droidapp2.actvities.MainActivity$3.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:287)
                                                                                   at com.firebase.client.core.ChildEventRegistration.fireEvent(ChildEventRegistration.java:48)
                                                                                   at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
                                                                                   at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

06-27 17:51:16.712 2938-3140/com.example.harrops.h20droidapp2 D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, _sc=MainActivity, _si=7357998494779803214, timestamp=1498585876708, fatal=1}]

Comment: Post the error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: seems  like Nullpointer , either `msearchname` or `url` is null , maybe both , put a nullity check

Comment: its String null error. but only when the item is not in my database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) docs

> An instance of the class passed in, populated with the data from this
>   snapshot, or `null if there is no data at this location.`

so add a nullity check

```
    if (msearchname!=null && url!=null && msearchname.toLowerCase().contains(searchapps.toLowerCase())) {
```

Note : `&&` is a short circuit operator , mean won't execute `if` in case of any false expression value.

Comment: i am glad that i could help , happy coding